# Differentiable, nonnegative derivative ae, nondecreasing?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I have been trying to prove or disprove:
Let $g$ be differentiable on the reals, have $g'(x)\geq 0$ except countably many values, then $g$ is non-decreasing.

The main problem I face is that I don't have that $g'$ is continuous. Otherwise fundamental theorem of calculus $\int_a^b g'=g(b)-g(a)\geq 0$ will do the job nicely.

I can't find counter examples either.

Thanks for help!

Comment: In Saks' book "Theory of the Integral", this proposition is said to be true (see theorem $7.9$ page $206$)

Comment: @charMD Thanks. I believe the propostion in the book is more general than what I need to prove.

Comment: Btw, reading your answer I'm wondering : when you said "almost everywhere", did you mean at each point except countably many, or except at a set of measure $0$ ?

Comment: @charMD you are right. I made a mistake, it should be except countably many.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I have come up with a proof. Please comment if there is something not right with it.

Suppose to the contrary $g$ is NOT nondecreasing on $\mathbb{R}$. There exists $x_1,x_2\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $x_1<x_2$ but $g(x_2)<g(x_1)$. By Mean Value Theorem, there exists $c\in (x_1,x_2)$ such that $$g'(c)=\frac{g(x_2)-g(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}<0.$$

Let $$L=g'(c)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{g(c+h)-g(c)}{h}<0.$$
This means there exists a $\delta>0$ such that for $|h|<\delta$, $$|\frac{g(c+h)-g(c)}{h}-L|<\epsilon$$ for any $\epsilon>0$. Choose $0<\epsilon<-L$ such that $\epsilon+L<0$. Then for $|h|<\delta$, $$\frac{g(c+h)-g(c)}{h}<\epsilon+L<0.$$

Take $h\in (0,\delta)$. Note that there are uncountable choices of $h$. Then $g(c+h)<g(c)$. For each choice of $h$, by MVT again, there exists $d_h\in(c,c+h)$ such that $$g'(d_h)=\frac{g(c+h)-g(c)}{(c+h)-c}<0.$$

This contradicts that $g'(x)\geq 0$ except countably many points.

Comment: In the last part of your proof, it is not sure that the set $\{d_h,\ h \in (0,\delta ) \}$ is uncountable. (It is not finite, but may be countable). And even if it was uncountable, you couldn't say much about its measure.

Comment: I see the problem.. $d_h$ may be repeated in the sense that $d_{h_1}=d_{h_2}$.